# TFS Build - Get Assembly Version Info

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild

Is there a simple way to set the TFS Build Number to be an Assembly Version during build?

I've seen many examples of the other way around (i.e. a build number updates the assembly version).

We already use the SharedAssemblyInfo implementation from [here](https://gist.github.com/RichardSlater/ce86d5cf5b645a5b068a), so we would like to leverage this setup during the build process.

Currently using TFS 2012 with Release Management template (ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying the build process template? No. Even then, the build number is set prior to compilation (or, IIRC, even syncing the code from source control), so you're in for a wild ride trying to get the behavior you want.

Comment: I've modified the build process template to allow pre-build/post-build script runs (http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-script-hooks-for-tfs-2012-builds). Is it not possible to get Assembly Version during pre-build via Powershell script?

Comment: You would have to parse AssemblyInfo.cs. If you're executing something pre-build, it's before you have an assembly. If you don't have an assembly, you can't get the assembly's metadata.

Comment: What I really need to do is have AssemblyInfo match the Release/Sprint in TFS. So, MyProgram.dll would be 1.5.(rev) for Release 1 Sprint 5. So, if this is possible the other way around (updating AssemblyInfo from the build template), then open to suggestions. Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to get the assembly version early enough in the process as you have not done a get on the files yet. There build number is set by the controller, not the agent. This will however be possible in TFS 2015.